# Magento redirecting page.html?utm_campaign to page.html

Tags: 301-redirect

My magento installation is stripping out URL variables by 301'ing to itself.

E.g:

*www.mysite.co.uk/page.html?umm_campaign=123...*

to

*www.mysite.co.uk.page.html*

This means my GA is not tracking properley amongst other problems.

Is there a setting to disable this functionality?

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add something like this to your .htaccess file. It should keep the query string variables in place.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Magento is doing the 301 redirect post .htaccess, if i put an exit; at the top of index.php, the url variables remain.